# Change font style of Label Docorator

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to append a suffix to some file names. I create a label decorator as given below and it is working correctly. But I also want to make my decoration **bold**. I implemented *IFontDecorator* but it's `decoratFont()` is not getting called. Can anyone guide me how should I make my decoration appear bold.

```
public class ConfigFileDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator, IFontDecorator {
    private Font boldFont;

    public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
        try {
            String platform = getPlatformName(element);
            if (platform == null) {
                return;
            }

            decoration.addSuffix(" [" + platform + "]");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Activator.log(e);
        }
    }

    @Override   
    public Font decorateFont(Object element) {
        try {
            String platform = getPlatformName(element);
            if (platform == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (boldFont != null) {
                return boldFont;
            }

            Font defaultFont = JFaceResources.getDefaultFont();
            FontData[] fontData = defaultFont.getFontData();
            for (int i = 0; i < fontData.length; i++) {
                fontData[i].setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
            }               
            boldFont = new Font(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), fontData);
            return boldFont;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Activator.log(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ILightweightLabelDecorator` doesn't support `IFontDecorator`.

Instead you call the `setFont` method of the `IDecoration` parameter passed to the `decorate` method.

Comment: Is there any other Label decorator which would support styling only the decoration part.

Comment: The non-lightweight `ILabelDecorator` supports `IFontDecorator`.